# Eclipse: how to show the Markers tab in the bottom pane

Tags: java, eclipse

Out of box, Eclipse has a few tabs such as Properties, Search, and Console in its bottom pane when it is in edit mode.

A while ago, by accident I closed a tab called "Markers" (I hope my memory serves me right). In this tab, I can see Java compilation errors.

How can I show the Markers tab in the bottom pane?

Thanks and regards.

Edit: I am using version Luna 4.4.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Markers is a part of General view folder. You can show it up from "Window>Show View>Other". You will find Markers either by expanding 'General' or by searching for it.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the Problems view even though what it shows is Markers.

Windows menu > Show View > Problems View

If the Problems view is not listed there just select Other then search for "Problem".

Comment: It is just called Markers in the place you specified. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Are you using Eclipse in English?

Comment: Ah, there is both a Problems view and a Markers view, but I've forgotten the difference. (I think the Problems view will show things that are not Markers as well as the markers but I don't remember.)

Comment: Alex, yes, I use the English/Luna version.

Comment: I had forgotten there was a second view called Markers, note that if you reset the Java perspective it's the Problems view that is shown, not Markers. (right click on the perspective button, select "reset")

Comment: I am using Java EE perspective. Thanks for your info. Good to know. Cheers!

Comment: That explains it, the EE perspective uses the Markers view but the Java perspective uses the Problems view. (But I have no idea why.)

Comment: Alex, thanks so much for the communication and help. Cannot say enough thank-you. Have a great day and weekend!!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of Eclipse you have, but go to the menu at the top, then select Window - Show view - Other- General - Markers.